Select text in textarea, delete it by backspace/delete to add CSS for another element
I have a div and a textarea.
I want to achieve two things:

If I select all the text in the textarea, then press backspace or delete key,
this will add the CSS style border: 1px solid red to the div. That means: Detect if all the text was selected or not before delete.

If not all of the text was selected but just a long press on backspace or delete key occurred, delete all the text, this will add the CSS style border: 1px solid red border to the div. Here I don't want to add the CSS style or delete the text on just a short press. Just after a long key press, and all the text should be deleted add the CSS style added.


This is my code:
<div id="getcss">html contents</div>
<textarea name="new" id="message">text content</textarea>


<script>                                            
$('#message').keyup(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46){
// Code for 1:
// if select all the text in textarea 
// then press on backspace or delete 
// will add 1px solid red border to div id="getcss" .
// Code for 2:
// if text not selected in textarea 
// and press on backspace or delete 
// and still press untill delete all the text  
// will add 1px solid red border to div id="getcss" .
}
});

</script>


Your both condition will be covered if you apply a check of textarea data completely removed or not
Based on check apply a class over div and write desired css for that class.
Working snippet:


$('#message').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
      $('#getcss').addClass('bordered');
    }
  }
});
.bordered {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="getcss">html contents</div>
<br><br>
<textarea name="new" id="message">text content</textarea>




In case you ever don't care how the textarea was emptied, you can get this behavior with CSS alone:


#getcss:has(+ textarea:invalid) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<div id="getcss">html contents</div>
<textarea name="new" id="message" required>text content</textarea>




Very intersting invalid property that works with required minlength ...attribute (+1)
